# Qt QMenu position

Tags: qt

I would like to have a QMenu above a QToolButton, without rewritting a custom widget playing with relative/absolute size and positions (meaning without coding :)).

Does anyone know if it is possible using styles or properties? I didn't see anything like in the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "above"?  Do you want a particular item in the menu bar aligned with a particular button, or do you want a menu to appear over the button when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a button with menu see `setMenu( QMenu* )`. This will create a menu, which will appear on a left click over the button. **Not** popup menu on right click.